# why yum update --assumeno return exit code 1 while yum progress installation is ok

Tags: linux, centos, yum

we are doing `yum update --assumeno` , just to check if simulate yum installation is fine

the target of yum is upgrade Linux version `7.1` to `7.8`

so we did the following

```
yum update --assumeno --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=RHEL78-repo
```

and last lines are

```
.
.
.
.
 rhsm-gtk                                                        x86_64                       1.21.10-2.el7                                          rhel76-repo                       470 k
 shim-x64                                                        x86_64                       15-1.el7                                               rhel76-repo                       655 k
 subscription-manager-rhsm-certificates                          x86_64                       1.21.10-2.el7                                          rhel76-repo                       212 k
 volume_key-libs                                                 x86_64                       0.3.9-8.el7                                            rhel76-repo                       140 k
 webkitgtk4                                                      x86_64                       2.20.5-1.el7                                           rhel76-repo                        26 M
 webkitgtk4-jsc                                                  x86_64                       2.20.5-1.el7                                           rhel76-repo                       4.6 M
 webkitgtk4-plugin-process-gtk2                                  x86_64                       2.20.5-1.el7                                           rhel76-repo                       9.6 M
 xdg-desktop-portal                                              x86_64                       1.0.2-1.el7                                            rhel76-repo                       249 k
 xdg-desktop-portal-gtk                                          x86_64                       1.0.2-1.el7                                            rhel76-repo                       157 k

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================================================================================
Install   18 Packages (+110 Dependent packages)
Upgrade  829 Packages

Total download size: 833 M
Exiting on user command
Your transaction was saved, rerun it with:
 yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx.2020-11-01.07-53.6Vgx2y.yumtx
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

so when we did after yum completed `echo $?` we get `1`

```
echo $?
1
```

why we get - `1` and not `0` ? if yum not show errors or dependencies problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yum` will always return 1 if you answer "No" (or use `--assumeno`).

If you want a "dry-run" mode for yum, install `yum-plugin-tsflags` package and then run `yum update -y --setopt tsflags=test`. It will download the packages, run the transaction check and everything but the package installation/removal itself is a no-op.